# TypeScript extract union type from tuple

Tags: typescript

Is it possible to extract union type from tuple? Here is an example what I have in mind:

```
declare let op: ['1', '2/1'] | ['1', '2/2'];
declare let op2: ['1', '2/1' | '2/2'];

op = op2; // Error
op2 = op; // OK
```

Is it possible to convert `op2` type to `op`? Or maybe I should take another approach on this?

Comment: The compiler doesn't see those as equivalent types despite the fact that the same values are assignable to it. [Unions are not aggressively propagated down into properties](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/8289).  You might need to use a type assertion and move on.