# Split tuple of unions into union of tuples in TypeScript

Tags: typescript

This question is similar to [TypeScript extract union type from tuple](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59736074/typescript-extract-union-type-from-tuple), but instead of asking why one isn't assignable to the other (I understand that bit), I want to know how to make a function or type split `['a' | 'b', number]` into `['a', number] | ['b', number]`.

Suppose I have this contrived code:

```ts
// the return type of this needs to change, and ideally it can infer F and S without 
// specifying them the function call
function treatAsConstants<
  F,
  S,
  T extends [F, S][] = [F, S][]
>(array: T): (readonly [F, T[number][1]])[] {
  return array;
}

const array = treatAsConstants<'a' | 'b', number>([['a', 1], ['b', 2]]);

// desired: (readonly ['a', number] | readonly ['b', number])[]
// actual: (readonly ['a' | 'b', number])[]
type A = typeof array;
```

In a later function that takes in `array`, I need to `Extract` `['a', number]` and `['b', number]` in order to determine the shape of an object.  However, `['a' | 'b', number]` fits neither of those types.

Here's my best attempt at splitting the unions, but it just gives me exactly what I started with.

```ts
type SplitUnions<
  TKey extends string,
  TVal,
  O extends { [K in TKey]: [K, TVal] } = { [K in TKey]: [K, TVal] }
> = [O[TKey][0], O[TKey][1]];

type Split = SplitUnions<'a' | 'b', number>;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was pretty close.  Instead of `[O[TKey][0], O[TKey][1]]` I simply needed `O[TKey]`.