# Extract<[T, V], [U, any]> where T is a union type and U is not

Tags: typescript

A while back, I posted [Infer shape of result of Object.fromEntries() in TypeScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63061180/infer-shape-of-result-of-object-fromentries-in-typescript), and received the following answer which I found to work fine until two days ago.

```ts
declare global {
  interface ObjectConstructor {
    fromEntries<
      A extends ReadonlyArray<readonly [PropertyKey, any]>
    >(array: A): { [K in A[number][0]]: Extract<A[number], readonly [K, any]>[1] }
  }
}
```

This works as long as `A[number][0]` maps to exactly one type in each element.  However, it breaks if it you tell it that each tuple's first element is a union type.

```ts
const x = Object.fromEntries(
  [['a', 1], ['b', 2], ['c', 'foo']] as (['a' | 'b', number] | ['c', string])[]
);
// typeof x = { a: never, b: never; c: string; }
```

The issue is that `K` will always be exactly one of `'a' | 'b'`, and since `'a' | 'b'` does not extend `'a'`, it fails.  I know how to [split a tuple of unions into unions of tuples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63079665/split-tuple-of-unions-into-union-of-tuples-in-typescript), but only if the second element's type is the same for all tuples, which is not necessarily the case here.

How can I fixup the `Object.fromEntries()` definition to handle union-type keys?

[TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=5.1.6#code/C4TwDgpgBAYgTgewLYFEB2w4EsIGcA8AKlBAB7ARoAmuUcEAhlQmgDYhQAU9TL7UAbQAKiSHFABpCCAA0UBmhABdAJQClAPigBeKAG8AUFGOCJULGiiEBaAK5IARhDhKBABiVKAXFBTk4DADGwEQ29k4ucjzMbBwCEnIKyhoCAIxKANwGAL5ZBqCQUAAaOrCIqBjYePicAgDkDHVQAD5QdQ51cnaOzkotgnWBnVC4mBYA5qrqGnmBLKNQpD4luoYm8j6pMkYmDj4ATNvrgT51AGYICJ05eQD0t1AAsgwcCHBQSC9QaAjAUE5QAAWEFYYDOtlY+XA0AAymBWFhgABVNBYeb4HaEKQcMgUai0UbYNDjI5WABqDFY2y0q1M5ksWOk3lMckIFNYfWyAkZygyQA)

Comment: It's not pretty but it works: https://tsplay.dev/Wv1dnm

Comment: @kelsny Interesting!  I hadn't realized you could use `as` in a `[K in X]` clause.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out (I think)!  Rather than use `Extract`, simply use intersections.

```ts
declare global {
  interface ObjectConstructor {
    fromEntries<
      A extends ReadonlyArray<readonly [PropertyKey, any]>
    >(array: A): { [K in A[number][0]]: (A[number] & readonly [K, unknown])[1] };
  }
}
```

This at least works for all my test cases.